# How to convert Clipboard Image BMP to PNG using Pillow package without saving and then loading

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, png, clipboard, bmp

I would like to convert an image obtained from the Windows Clipboard to PNG format **without** having to **save** and then **reload**.

As per the code below, I am saving the clipboard image and then reloading it. 
Is there a way to convert the image to PNG format without those extra steps, such that the

- `PIL.BmpImagePlugin.DibImageFile`  gets converted to
- `PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile`

**Here is the current code:**

```py
from PIL import ImageGrab, Image

# Get the clipboard image
img1 = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()

# Save the image from the clipboard to file
img1.save('paste.png', 'PNG')
print("Image Type1:", type(img1))

# Load the image back in
img2 = Image.open('paste.png')
print("Image Type2:", type(img2))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Image Type1: <class 'PIL.BmpImagePlugin.DibImageFile'>
Image Type2: <class 'PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile'>
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39886326/how-to-change-image-format-without-writing-it-to-disk-using-python-pillow) might prove helpful - the idea is to save the image to an in-memory `BytesIO` object, and reload it from there. We're still saving and loading, but not to disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per some help from [Seon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13145954/seon)'s comment, this got me on the right track, and fulfilled my requirements.

As per Seon:

> "the idea is to save the image to an **in-memory** `BytesIO object`, and reload it from there. We're still saving and loading, but **not to disk**."

Which is exactly what I wanted.
**Here is the code I used:**

```py
from PIL import ImageGrab, Image
import io


def convertImageFormat(imgObj, outputFormat="PNG"):
    newImgObj = imgObj
    if outputFormat and (imgObj.format != outputFormat):
        imageBytesIO = io.BytesIO()
        imgObj.save(imageBytesIO, outputFormat)
        newImgObj = Image.open(imageBytesIO)
        
    return newImgObj


# Get the clipboard image and convert to PNG
img1 = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
img2 = convertImageFormat(img1)

# Check the types
print("Image Type1:", type(img1))
print("Image Type2:", type(img2))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Image Type1: <class 'PIL.BmpImagePlugin.DibImageFile'>
Image Type2: <class 'PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile'>
```